# Representing a four-vector by a rank 2 tensor

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry

When representing a 3-vector $(x,y,z)$ as a skew-symmetric matrix like this:

$X=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -z & y\\
z & 0 & -x\\
-y & x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$X$ transforms a a rank 2 tensor under $SO(3)$:
$X' = R  X  R^T$. Now I was trying to generalize this to $4$ dimensions by representing a four-vector $(t,x,y,z)$ by the matrix:

$X=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & t & t& t\\
t & 0 & -z & y\\
t & z & 0 & -x\\
t & -y & x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

I chose this form because it uses the generators of the Lorentz group in the same way the representation of the 3-vector uses the generators of the rotation group. However this doesn't yield the correct transformation behavior. Applying for example a boost in the $x$-direction, yields:

$\begin{pmatrix}γ&-γβ&0&0\\ -γβ&γ&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0&t&t&t\\ t&0&-z&y\\ t&z&0&-x\\ t&-y&x&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}γ&-γβ&0&0\\ -γβ&γ&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2βγ^2t&β^2γ^2t+γ^2t&γt+βγz&γt-βγy\\ γ^2t+β^2γ^2t&-2βγ^2t&-βγt-γz&γy-βγt\\ γt-βγz&γz-βγt&0&-x\\ γt+βγy&-βγt-γy&x&0\end{pmatrix}$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A lot is wrong with your attempt, but, close in spirit, there is the 2x2 [spinor map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Relation_to_the_Möbius_group), which is standard lore in special relativity.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the spinor representation. It's this representation that prompted me to read a few wikipedia articles and it's there that I found the tensor representation of a regular vector, which in turn prompted the above question.

Comment: The fundamental rep of SO(3) is isomorphic to its adjoint. This accident only happens in SO(3). In SO(4), the fundamental and the adjoint are non-isomorphic (the former being four-dimensional and the latter six-dimensional). So your attempt is doomed to failure.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform:  that looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree.